# disable validation from all properties model inside another model

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have model which has got two other models because on the website user can see note and user can write comment:

```
public class NoteAndCommentViewModel
{
    public Note Note { get; set; }
    public Comment Comment { get; set; }
}

public class Note
{
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Summary { get; set; }
}

public class Comment
{
    [Required]
    public string Author { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

**How can I disable validation in NoteAndCommentViewModel for all properties for Note?** Because now in action controller my model is always not valid because after submit form I return Comment model so Note model is null:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(NoteAndCommentViewModel noteAndCommentViewModel)
{            
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //.....
    }

    //.....
}
```

Comment: `if (ModelState.ContainsKey("PropertyName"))
    ModelState["PropertyName"].Errors.Clear();`

Answer (score 0):

This classes must be a in your model folder and viewmodel file is in another folder where you can add all this properties which need to be validated

```
public class NoteAndCommentViewModel
{

    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Summary { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Author { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```